# GLM look at object outside of the screen

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a cube with vertex at 1 and -1 (1 1 1, 1 1 -1, etc).

Currently I'm using only the view matrix and set the projection to be identity:

```
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
mat4 view = glm::lookAt(vec3(0,0,3),
                        vec3(0,0,0),
                        vec3(0,0,1));
mat4 mvp = view;
GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation(p_myGLSL->getProgramID(), "mvp");
glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, countV);

glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Vertex shading code:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;   
uniform mat4 mvp;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
}
```

VBO, VAO code:

```
// fill values into VBO
GLuint positionBufferHandle;
glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferHandle);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, countV*sizeof(float), positionData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Vertex array object
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle);
glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

// Read into vertex shader
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLubyte *) NULL);

glutMainLoop();
```

Why is it showing a blank screen for now?

P/S: If I create the view matrix manually it works:

```
mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), vec3(-centerx, -centery, -centerz));
mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1), vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2));
mat4 mvp = scale * translate;
```

Comment: can you please show us more? may be something is wrong in other parts.

Comment: Are you specifying your opengl version in your vertex shader?

Answer (score 1):

Use vec3(0,1,0) as up vector. When you are looking at (0,0,0) from (0,0,3), you looking in (0,0,-1) direction. The up vector should be perpendicular to this vector, which you can use vec3(0, 1, 0) vector. So, change the `view` matrix assignment part to:

```
mat4 view = glm::lookAt(vec3(0,0,3),
                        vec3(0,0,0),
                        vec3(0,1,0));
```

Also, Add `#version 430` or whatever GLSL version which you are using to beginning of your vertex shader. `layout` qualifer is part of OpenGL core, since OpenGL 4.1 not earlier.

Comment: It's still not working yet. Please check update post. If I set the view matrix manually it works though.

Comment: @DzungNguyen Use vec3(0,1,0) as up vector. When you are looking at (0,0,0) from (0,0,3), you looking in (0,0,-1) direction. The up vector should be perpendicular to this vector, which you can use `vec3(0, 1, 0)` vector

Comment: It turns out that after the view, object is outside of the clip volume. I added the projection matrix and it works.

Comment: It seems so strange to me! Because now you are just multiplying an `identity` matrix with `mvp` which will change nothing. Are you creating an `ortho` or `perspective` projection matrix?

Comment: I add: mvp = proj * view, where proj = glm::perspective(radians(60.0f), 1,0.f, 10.0f). Without the proj matrix it's blank.